# need to copy images from 1000 subfolders into one single folder

Tags: command-line, bash, copy

How can I copy around 1000 subfolders each having 4000 images into one single folder named all_images?

I tried the following:

```
$ cp upload/*/* all_images/
```

and got the following error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/cp: Argument list too long
```

Please note that I tried this on two small subfolders and it worked.

Comment: You should also be aware of the filesystem performance hit with a directory with 4 million files.

Comment: @ubfan1 what are our alternatives? should we just live them be at their current structure and modify our python code to go through each of these subdirectories to read images?

Comment: @ubfan1 additionally, is there a link that talks about performance hit with 4M files in one directory? why is it not hit if these 4M are distributed in 1000 directories?

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/43133/filesystem-large-number-of-files-in-a-single-directory  Filesystems may be tweaked at creation for files (inodes etc.) but just because you can do it, doesn't mean you'd be happy with the result.Try tests on a directory with 30,000 and 60,000 files, that's a usual practical cutoff.

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/584315/placing-many-10-million-files-in-one-folder for some issues and suggested alternatives.